# multiple sort order on same field

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following example:

```
+---------+------------+
| value   | name       |
+---------+------------+
|      42 | abresas    |
|       0 | dionyziz   |
|       6 | dionyziz2  |
|       0 | izual      |
|       8 | kokos      |
|      37 | kostis90gr |
|       0 | test       |
|      35 | usertest   |
+---------+------------+
```

I want to sort this in ascending order of value but I want all the names with value 0 to display at bottom. So the sort order should be:
6,8,35,37,42,0,0,0

Any idea if this is possible with sql or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure. Use the [IF function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
ORDER BY IF(value=0,1,0), value
```

Comment: Added a link to the IF function documentation because I didn't know it existed! Thanks.

Comment: That was great thanks, to sort by desc all i had to do was add DESC at end of value and it worked! Mind explaining what 0,1,0 does?

Comment: `IF(value=0,1,0)` is equivalent to `CASE WHEN value = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` - an identical query plan should be generated for each, but confirm this yourself. `IF` is a MySQL extension to SQL, but `CASE` is part of the ANSI standard. Because they are functionally equivalent, but one is proprietary, I would recommend the form universally understood by SQL products.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you just have to adjust the order by clause:

```
order by (case when value = 0 then 999999 else value end)
```

is one way to do it, assuming to have a maximum.  Another more general way is:

```
order by (case when value = 0 then 1 else 0 end), value
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I really *hate* using magic numbers like your first suggestion. By the time I have a record with value = 1034120, I've forgotten all about the magic number and have to start wondering why my sort is off.

Comment: I agree with lc. My upvote is for your second code snippet, which I think is the best answer so far.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the UNION keyword for combining the results of two different queries like this:

```
(select * from tableName where value>0 order by value) 
union 
(select * from tableName where value=0)
```

Comment: The `ORDER BY` clause makes the database returns a cursor, which forces an order. In theory, a `UNION` of two result sets produces another result set, which has no order. In practice, the database engine physically materializes the result set as all the rows of the first result set followed by all the rows of the second result set, but it doesn't have to return rows in this order. It could as well materialize the second result set before the first, which would still be correct, but would break your ordering. Use an explicit `ORDER BY` clause instead.